# If statement not working based on Component props, see Edit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently trying to implement some basic authentication by wrapping a react Route element.

Here loggedIn is the hook value, and setLoggedIn is the "setter". The setter is passed by props to the "Login" component which correctly sets the hook's value. However, the "App" return function renders with the old value.

## Functional Component:

```
function App() {
    const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
    
    return (
            <Router>
                <div className="App">
                    <Route path="/budget" component= {BudgetDisplay}/>
                    <Route path="/login" render={() => <Login loggedIn={loggedIn} setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn}/>}/>    

                    <PrivateRoute path="/admin" loggedIn={loggedIn} component={Admin}/>
                </div>
            </Router>
   );
}

export default App;
```

## Route Component wrapper:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, loggedIn, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
        loggedIn === true 
        ? <Component {...props}/>
        : <Redirect to="/login"/>
    )}/>
)
```

As the return utilises the previous value, the redirect component is rendered instead of the correct Component.

I am aware of the useEffect method, however I am not sure how to implement it such that "App" returns the correct value.

I have tried making the same Functional Component as a Class Component using setState instead, but ran into the same issue.

## Edit:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, loggedIn, ...rest }) => {
    console.log(loggedIn)
    
    if ( loggedIn ) {
        return <Route {...rest} render={(props) => <Component {...props}/>}/>;
    } else { 
        return <Route {...rest} render={() => <Redirect to="/login"/>}/>;
    };
};
```

The correct value is logged here, loggedIn = true, however the Redirect is returned.

Comment: Are you able to `console.log(loggedIn)` before your return statement in `App`?

Comment: Yes, the correct value is printed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was removing the {...rest} from PrivateRoute, still don't know why though.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, loggedIn, ...rest }) => {
    if ( loggedIn ) {
        return <Route {...rest} render={(props) => <Component {...props}/>}/>;
    } else { 
        return <Route render={() => <Redirect to="/login"/>}/>;
    };
};
```